# How to detect double free on device?

Tags: objective-c, ios, xcode, memory-management

I am getting the following error

```
malloc: * error for object 0x****: pointer being freed was not allocated * set a breakpoint in malloc_error_break to debug
```

but only on devices,  not on simulator.
So, I can't profile my app for `NSZombie` on device. Is there any way to find extra release without manual debugging on the device?

Comment: Could you please show some code? Is difficult to say something without any code

Comment: Thanks for your attention, but no code needed for this question.
I was asking not for error fixing but for tool to detect NSZombie on device. And it was an year ago, I don't even remember what project was the reason of this question.

Comment: Well, actually you can detect zombies on device, but you can't debug them. Just edit your project scheme: NSZombieEnabled = YES